# USB2 device on USB3 System, will it use asynchronous notifications?

Tags: usb

Imagine I plug a USB2 device that has interrupts and sends NAKs when it has no new interrupt data into an USB3 HUB of a system with an USB3 Host Controller.

What happens between the Host Controller and the USB3 Hub? Will the HUB poll the device continuously and between the HUB and the Host Controller, it will use asynchronous notification? Or will the Host Controller send polls all the way down to the device?

Comment: USB3 ports include a completely separate USB2 interface with its own wires, logical USB 2 host, etc. As far as your device is concerned it's not plugged into a usb3 device.

Comment: @user1850479 yeah but the HUB knows. So my question is, does the HUB pass-through the USB2 connection upwards and bothers the root hub with it, or does it translate it to USB3? Still learning about USB3 so I'm not sure!